# Improving jQuery scrolldown animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, easing

I'm pretty new to client side scripting and I'm still learning.

I've written this JS plugin which animates blocks of HTML (fade-in from left/top/right/bottom) as you scroll down the page.

Everything seems to be works correctly, but was just wondering if there is anyone who could suggest how I can improve on this?

e.g:

- Reduce the size of the code.
- Structure the plugin better.
- Stop repetitive code.
- Increase browser compatibility.
- Make better use of jQuery keywords.

Really, just doing the same thing, but, written better!

CSS:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.animate {
    position: relative;
}

.bg-info {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="left" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="0" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="top" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="500" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="bottom" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="1000" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="right" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="1500" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.animateSliders = function(options) {
            var style = { opacity: "0", "-ms-opacity": "0" };
            var settings = $.extend({
                offset: 80,
                distance : 200,
                animation: "left",
                easing: "easeInOutBack",
                speed: 1000,
                delay: 0
            }, options);

            $(".animate").each(function () {
                loadvalues($(this));
                if (settings.animation == 'left') {
                    $(this).css({ left: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
                }
                if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                    $(this).css({ top: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
                }
                if (settings.animation == 'right') {
                    $(this).css({ right: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
                }
                if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                    $(this).css({ bottom: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
                }
            });

            $(window).on("scroll load", function() {
                $(".animate").each(function () {
                    loadvalues($(this)); 
                    var i = parseFloat(settings.offset) / 100;
                    var trigger = $(window).height() * i + $(window).scrollTop();
                    var position = $(this).offset().top;

                    if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                        position = position - settings.distance;
                    }
                    if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                        position = position + settings.distance;
                    }

                    if (position < trigger) {
                        if (settings.animation == 'left') {
                            $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'left': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                        }
                        if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                            $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'top': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                        }
                        if (settings.animation == 'right') {
                            $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'right': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                        }
                        if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                            $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'bottom': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                        }
                    };
                });
            });

            function loadvalues(obj) {
                if (obj.attr('data-animation')) {
                    settings.animation = obj.data("animation");
                };

                if (obj.attr('data-offset')) {
                    settings.offset = obj.data("offset");
                };

                if (obj.attr('data-distance')) {
                    settings.distance = obj.data("distance");
                };

                if (obj.attr('data-easing')) {
                    settings.easing = obj.data("easing");
                };

                if (obj.attr('data-speed')) {
                    settings.speed = obj.data("speed");
                };

                if (obj.attr('data-delay')) {
                    settings.delay = obj.data("delay");
                };
            }
        };
    }(jQuery));

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.animateSliders({offset : 200});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a few quick notes, this code block:

```
if (settings.animation == 'left') {
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'left': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
if (settings.animation == 'top') {
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'top': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
if (settings.animation == 'right') {
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'right': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'bottom': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
```

Is performing the same action no matter what the value is, so you could reduce it to either:

```
if (settings.animation) {
    var animationOptions = {
       opacity: 1
    };
    animationOptions[settings.animation] = '0px';
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate(animationOptions, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
```

or checking that the value is one of 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'

```
if (~['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'].indexOf(settings.animation)) {
    var animationOptions = {
       opacity: 1
    };
    animationOptions[settings.animation] = '0px';
    $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate(animationOptions, settings.speed, settings.easing);
}
```

You could apply the same reduction to this code block:

```
$(".animate").each(function () {
    loadvalues($(this));
    if (settings.animation == 'left') {
        $(this).css({ left: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
    }
    if (settings.animation == 'top') {
        $(this).css({ top: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
    }
    if (settings.animation == 'right') {
        $(this).css({ right: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
    }
    if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
        $(this).css({ bottom: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
    }
});
```

Additionally, your `loadValues` function could be reduced to a couple lines of code if you get all `data-` attributes and iterate the list:

```
function loadvalues(obj) {
   var dataKeys = obj.data();
   for(var key in dataKeys) {
     settings[key] = dataKeys[key];
   }
}
```